# Java Socket Data received unordered

Tags: java, android

I am collecting data from Android App(Accelerometer and Gyro) and send it to Desktop app via Java Socket  but in high rates 
(SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST,SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)

Notes :

- readingsList : contains all reading from sensors
- I remove from list the data being sent to server
- Only data sent once and i made sure it's ordered from client side 
  but i got them unordered in server side ( I received all data but not ordered)
- processData(String reading) function may takes time but not too much

Client Code :

```
    class SocketClientThread implements Runnable {

    public SocketClientThread(){

    }
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && breathingStarted) {
            try {

                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);


                PrintWriter out =
                        new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                socket.setSendBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                socket.setReceiveBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                int lastCount = readingsList.size();

                out.println(readingsList); 
                out.flush();
                out.close(); 
                int toberemoved = lastCount;   
                if(readingsList.size() > 0){
                    for (int i = 0; i < toberemoved; i++) {
                        readingsList.remove(0);
                    }
                }


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();   
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Server Code  :

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    serverSocket.setSoTimeout(minutes*60*1000);

Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(!isStopped)
        {
            try
            {

                Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
                connection.setReceiveBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                connection.setSendBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);


                BufferedReader input =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));


                PrintWriter out =
                        new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);

                String inputLine; 
                while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    recentReading = inputLine; 
                    String oldReading = recentReading;
                    String modifiedReading = oldReading.replace("[", "");
                    modifiedReading = modifiedReading.replace("]", "");
                    String [] readings = modifiedReading.split(",");
                    for (int i = 0; i < readings.length; i++) {
                        String currentReading = readings[i].trim();
                        String [] tokens = currentReading.split("_");
                         processData(currentReading);


                    }
                }
            }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
            {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        statusVal.setText("Socket timed out!");
                    }
                });

                break;
            }catch(SocketException s)
            {
                if(serverSocket.isClosed()){
                    display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            statusVal.setText("Disconnected");
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
};
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

I am getting data after it's time (not ordered)

Comment: What type is `readingsList`? There are types of `List` that ignore order for efficiency.

Comment: List<String>readingsList
and i created it like that :
readingsList =  Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

I added it to readlingsList ordered >> i made sure of that in client side

Comment: I mean how it is created. `new List<String>()` is not possible. What specific type is it; or better: how are you creating `readingsList`?

Comment: readingsList =  Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

it's updated by multiple threads so i created it like that

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. What do you mean by "unordered"? Is it possible that some network packets take more time than others and break the order? If that is so then consider adding some kind of index or timestamp to the data you are sending, so you can make sure the data is received in the correct order.

Comment: i am using TCP Sockets so data expected to be received ordered in server side if it's sent ordered from client
I am adding Timestamp to the reading but should i maintain its order in server side or assume it's received ordered ??

Comment: You can safely assume that the data you are sending is ordered as TCP packets are indexed and put together for you. One concern I have is that while doing `out.println(readingsList); 
                out.flush();
                out.close();` the other thread might add data and you read it next time.

Comment: Yes Threads add data when i removing the sent ones but i used the toberemoved to save the old value of length so that i could remove only the sent ones

Comment: `out.println(readingsList); ` ? What does that  print if readingList is a List? Why are you creating a new Socket for every println?

Comment: this will write the toString of readingsList to the socket like a json :
"[reading_1_.12,reading_2.32,....]"

Comment: i suspect that processData(String reading)  takes time and this will affect socket buffer to process (remaining readings)so it maybe overwritten or something